# how to convert multi-line list to a single line list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
grid = []
grid.clear()
f = open('grid.csv','r')
for line in f :
    values = line.split()
    for n in range(0,20) :
        grid.append(values[n])
f.close()
grid
```

grid.csv is file containing grid of 20*20 integers.
the output prints a list with each element in separate line. I tried this

```
grid = list(map(lambda s: s.strip('\n'),grid))
```

but the output was still in separate lines

Comment: `grid = list(map(lambda s: s.strip('\n'),grid))`

Comment: A <map at 0x7f2317b270f0> output means that the return is a map not a list, simply surround it by list

Comment: second line is not valid because a list doesn't have that method (clear), check https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: surrounding by list returned same output i.e. in separate lines

Comment: @Juan it does in python 3 though https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple:

```
with open("grid.csv", "r") as f:
    grid = [item for line in f for item in line.split()]
```

Will give you a 1D list of your 2D data, provided that your integer grid in the `grid.csv` is indeed whitespace-separated. You can verify it by simply joining back the list with a space:

```
print(" ".join(grid))
```

Comment: yes it is in white space. now I've got all the integers in single line in a list using `list = [(" ".join(grid))]` still they are separated in with white space so couldnt be iterated.

Comment: @anon-bee-01 - If you want to iterate over them, just don't join them - they are already separated as a 1D list in the `grid`.

Comment: List will be still in 2D. I tried strip \n but still it's in 2D

Comment: Okay I do have in 1D now. Thanks @zwer